# How to compute DTW distance more faster in massive data set

Tags: python, performance, distance-matrix, dtw

I try to calculate the distance between time series data using dtw in Python. There are 10487 time series data, and each time series data has 37 data points.
I want to create a distance matrix of size 10487*10487 by calculating the distance between each time series data.

The code below was created to create a distance matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from fastdtw import fastdtw

df_array = df.iloc[:, 1:37].to_numpy()
dtwmatrix = np.zeros((len(df), len(df)))
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i):
        distance, path= fastdtw(df_array[i], df_array[j], dist=euclidean)
        dtwmatrix[i,j]=distance
```

My code is how to calculate the dtw distance between the i-th time series data and the j-th time series data and put the results in the i-th and j-th positions of the distance matrix.
DataFrame df is a dataset which is already imported. You don't need to consider about df and df_array.

The problem is that code execution takes too long. The loop takes 0.01 seconds, but the total number of dtw distances to be calculated is (1+10487)*10487/2=54983341, which takes about 152 hours.
For faster code execution, I would like you to give me some advice on code improvements.

Comment: Use a vectorized approach.  A nice resource for is this article by Divakar: https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method

Comment: @Lith Thanks! I'll apply it as you told me. Thank you for the good resource

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in need for a faster solution, the optimized implementation for a distance matrix available in the dtaidistance package takes about 30 seconds on a recent Macbook with 8 cores for 10487 series of length 37 (note that this toolbox requires rows to be the series):

```
df_array2 = np.random.random((10487, 37))
dtaidistance.dtw.distance_matrix_fast(df_array2)
```

More info on https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/dtw.html#dtw-between-multiple-time-series
(disclaimer, I am a co-author of the toolbox)

You are probably also not gaining much by using fastdtw since it is approximate and often not faster than regular DTW, thus no approximation, as shown by Wu and Keogh (https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.11246). If you want to speed up DTW it is more effective to use a window or employ pruning.